# Consume MQTT message on AMQP

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I tried to look around the web for an example or a solution, but whit no luck.. basically I have RabbitMQ that reside on a C# application sending messages in this way..

```
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 5672 };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        string message = "Hello World!";
        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "amqp.topic",
                             routingKey: "TestMQTT",
                             basicProperties: null,
                             body: body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
     }
```

and a simple Javascript client whit **MQTT Paho** js library (no nodejs) where I'm trying to consume the messages coming from the **AMQP** in this way:

```
var wsbroker = "localhost";  // mqtt websocket enabled broker
var wsport = 15675; // port for above
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport, "/ws",
    "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

    client.onConnect = function (responseObject){
        client.subscribe("TestMQTT");
    }
    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
        debug("CONNECTION LOST - " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    };

    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
        debug("RECEIVE ON " + message.destinationName + " PAYLOAD " + message.payloadString);
        print_first(message.payloadString);
    };
```

So far i'm not able to receive anything, can someone please point me in the right direction, possibly with some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to connect the client?  I don't see the `.connect` in your example above.

```
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
```